# Apaches Ignite doesn't serialize/deserialize Guavas LoadingCache

Tags: java, caching, guava, java-7, ignite

I'm using Java7 and I'm configuring Apaches Ignite (version 2.7.5) where the servers/clients are up and running. However, clients are unable to retrieve Guavas LoadingCache variable from the object (however ConcurrentHashMap is retrieved without issues). It seems that somehow on Ignites proxy calls the object is not serialized/deserialized correctly and I'm having trouble as Guavas docs says that LoadingCache/Cache implement Serializable.

In the following sample, MyContainer class and _foo1 are ok and were correctly serialized and deserialized but _foo (LoadingCache) was not.

```
public class MyContainer {

private final ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object> _foo1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private final LoadingCache<Object, Test> _foo = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().weakValues()
               .build(new CacheLoader<Object, Test>() {
                @Override public Test load(Object key) throws Exception {
                     return new Test(key);
                }});


}
```

Please let me know if you need more details and any help is greatly appreciated.
Best Regards, Hélder

**UPDATE**

Hello everyone, with Denis response I did more digging and found some mentions about `cfg.setMarshaller(new OptimizedMarshaller().setRequireSerializable(false));` and it worked. However, setMarshaller is deprecated and I'm not sure about this approach implications mainly at performance level.

Any read/explanation on what was the big deal behind the deprecation of this method?

Best Regards, Hélder

Comment: Your `CacheLoader` isn't serializable. The serialization error should tell you which class caused the failure.

Comment: @BenManes Thank you for the reply but the thing is that I don't have any error. The class where the LoadingCache/ConcurrentHM is serialized but LoadingCaches variable is simply returned as null.

Comment: What kind of issue do you have with the deserialization? Do you observe some exception, or some fields are just missing?

Comment: @Denis, no exceptions were found in logs but the variable returned null. Where I have Test it was a ReentrantLock however we decided to change the implementation and started using the Ignite Locks (together with LoadingCache and it is working now. I will "close" this question. Thank you for your time and knowledge :)

Comment: @HélderF. You are welcome :) Just in case, here is some reading about binary objects: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/binary-objects The main idea is that you are able to work with `BinaryObject`s without having corresponding classes and can access fields without deserializing the values entirely. If you use any marshaller other than binary (default one), you loose that ability along with ability of querying data over SQL, since it relies on the binary structure of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CacheBuilder` constructs an instance of `LocalCache.LocalLoadingCache`. It has a `writeReplace` method that messes up the serialization.

This issue has been fixed in Ignite 2.3: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6485

Which version of Ignite do you use? I would recommend upgrading to a fresh version of Ignite and switching to Java 8 or 11, since Java 7 is not supported by Ignite anymore.

Comment: Hi @Denis, thank you so much for the reply. At the moment I'm unable to upgrade to Java8 and I'm currently using Ignite Core 2.7.5.